# EURO equivalent of DXY?

Tags: foreign-exchange, currency, market-indexes

The U.S. Dollar Index, sometimes informally referred to as the "Dixie" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/U.S._Dollar_Index) is a nice index value to see the strength of the dollar. I was wondering if some equivalent index exists for the Euro, and if so what it is called? I cannot seem to find it.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euro_Currency_Index?

Answer (score 1):

These two CFD on Tradingview :

- [EXY](https://fr.tradingview.com/symbols/TVC-EXY/)
- [EURX](https://fr.tradingview.com/symbols/TVC-EXY/)